# How can I make sure the code runs all possibilities?

Tags: php, regex, for-loop

I'm stuck!

The code looks for words or sentences with preg_match_all and then replaces words and converts units.

Long text becomes `$Lines[]` through a `explode("\n", $Long_Text);`

A for loop runs through $Lines.

`If(preg_match_all)` finds if the line contains what it's looking for.

**Problem that occurs:**

Two of the same `preg_match_all()` is true, but because the code only looks once on each line it skips it.

**Other problem:**

3500ft is handled as 500 ft because `preg_match_all("/(\d{3,4})(ft)/", $Lines[$i], $output_array)` has the option of 3 digits.
How can I force it to first look for 4 digits then 3 digits.
Is my only option two preg_matches where the first one is `{4}` and the next `{3}`?

Example Long_Text:

> Isbildning 
>   Område 1a,1b,1c,2a,2b,3c,4a: Under hela perioden lätt till måttlig 
>   isbildning mellan 1500ft och FL090. 
>   Område 3a,3b: I början av perioden lätt till måttlig isbildning 
>   mellan FL060 och FL090.I mitten och mot slutet av perioden lätt till 
>   måttlig isbildning mellan 1500ft och FL090. 
>   Område 4b: Mot slutet av perioden lätt till måttlig isbildning mellan 
>   FL060 och FL090.
>
> Sikt/Väder/Moln 
>   Område 2a: Under hela perioden sikt över 8km, lokalt 3000-5000m i 
>   snöfall. Molnbas över 2000ft, lokalt 1500-2000ft. Molnöversida 
>   FL125. 
>   Område 1b: I början av perioden sikt över 8km, lokalt under 1500m i 
>   dis. Molnbas över 2000ft, lokalt 500-1000ft. Molnöversida >FL125. I 
>   mitten och mot slutet av perioden sikt över 8km, lokalt 1500-3000m i 
>   snöfall. Molnbas över 2000ft, lokalt 1000-1500ft. Molnöversida 
>   FL125. 
>   Område 4b,4c: Under hela perioden sikt över 8km. Molnbas över 2000ft. 
>   Molnöversida: Ingen prognos. 
>   Område 3a,3b: Under hela perioden sikt över 8km. Molnbas över 2000ft. 
>   Molnöversida >FL125. 
>   Område 1c,2b,3c,4a: I början och mitten av perioden sikt över 8km, 
>   lokalt under 1500m i dis. Molnbas över 2000ft, lokalt 500-1000ft. 
>   Molnöversida >FL125. Mot slutet av perioden sikt över 8km, lokalt 
>   3000-5000m i snöfall. Molnbas över 2000ft, lokalt 1500-2000ft. 
>   Molnöversida >FL125. 
>   Område 1a: Under hela perioden sikt över 8km, lokalt 1500-3000m i 
>   snöfall. Molnbas över 2000ft, lokalt 1000-1500ft. Molnöversida 
>   FL125.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($Lines);$i++) {
  if(preg_match_all("/(MELLAN) (\d{2}) (OCH) (\d{2}) (UTC)/", $Lines[$i], $output_array)){
    $Start = $output_array[1][0] . " " . $output_array[2][0] . " " . $output_array[3][0] . " " . $output_array[4][0] . " " . $output_array[5][0];
    $Goal =  $output_array[1][0] . " " . 1*($output_array[2][0]+$Diff) . " " . $output_array[3][0] . " " . 1*($output_array[4][0]+$Diff)  . " SVENSK TID";
    $Lines[$i] = str_replace($Start, $Goal, $Lines[$i]);
  }

  if(preg_match_all("/(\d{3,4}) (fot)/", $Lines[$i], $output_array)){
    $Start = $output_array[1][0] . " " . $output_array[2][0];
    $output_array[1][0] = ConvertMeter($output_array[1][0]);
    $Goal =  $output_array[1][0] . " meter";
    $Lines[$i] = str_replace($Start, $Goal, $Lines[$i]);
  }

  if(preg_match_all("/(\d{3,4}) (ft)/", $Lines[$i], $output_array)){
    $Start = $output_array[1][0] . " " . $output_array[2][0];
    $output_array[1][0] = ConvertMeter($output_array[1][0]);
    $Goal =  $output_array[1][0] . " meter";
    $Lines[$i] = str_replace($Start, $Goal, $Lines[$i]);
  }

  if(preg_match_all("/(\d{3,4})-(\d{3,4})(ft)/", $Lines[$i], $output_array)){
    $Start = $output_array[1][0] ."-" . $output_array[2][0] . "ft";
    $output_array[1][0] = ConvertMeter($output_array[1][0]);
    $output_array[2][0] = ConvertMeter($output_array[2][0]);
    $Goal =  $output_array[1][0] . "-" . $output_array[2][0] . " meter";
    $Lines[$i] = str_replace($Start, $Goal, $Lines[$i]);
  }

  if(preg_match_all("/(\d{3,4})(ft)/", $Lines[$i], $output_array)){
    $Start = $output_array[1][0] . $output_array[2][0];
    $output_array[1][0] = ConvertMeter($output_array[1][0]);
    $Goal =  $output_array[1][0] . " meter";
    $Lines[$i] = str_replace($Start, $Goal, $Lines[$i]);
  } 

  if(preg_match_all("/(FL)(\d{2,3})/", $Lines[$i], $output_array)){
    $Start = $output_array[1][0] . $output_array[2][0];
    $output_array[2][0] = ConvertMeter($output_array[2][0]*100);
    $Goal =  $output_array[2][0] . " meter";
    $Lines[$i] = str_replace($Start, $Goal, $Lines[$i]);
  }

  if(strpos($Lines[$i], "&gt;") !== false) $Lines[$i] = str_replace("&gt;", "över ", $Lines[$i]);
}
```

I truely hate the formatting on stackoverflow.

Comment: For your second question: `\b(?<range>(\d+)-(\d+)(?:ft|m|km))`, see a [demo here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kF4wM4/1)

Comment: Thank you!
That works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I present the ugliest solution ever....

```
preg_match_all("/\b(\d+)(ft)/", $Lines[$i], $output_array);
                    $x = count($output_array[1]);
                    for($d=0;$d<$x;$d++){
                        if(preg_match_all("/\b(\d+)(ft)/", $Lines[$i], $output_array)){
                            $Start = $output_array[1][0] . $output_array[2][0];
                            $output_array[1][0] = ConvertMeter($output_array[1][0]);
                            $Goal =  $output_array[1][0] . " meter";
                            $Lines[$i] = preg_replace("/".$Start."/", $Goal, $Lines[$i],1);
                        } 
                    }
```

First I preg_match it to see if the "value" exsists.
I do a count on the array and start a forloop on the number of times the preg_match found values.

It does the job, but it's ugly.